# Select from dropdown -> compare -> if match -> show picture

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Good day all,

I've got a code that reads the users from a database and puts them in a dropdown menu:

```
<?php           
mysql_connect('', '', '');
mysql_select_db ("");

$sql = "SELECT id,name FROM jos_users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


echo "<select name='deelnemers' onchange='copyId2textinput(this);'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Now i've got another database called jos_comprofiler with also an ID and also a avatar (image).

I was wondering if somebody give me some advise to compare the ID's from the 2 tables and then show the picture.

So for example, if i click on a user in the dropdown, it must look if there's a ID match with the other table, and if there is, show the picture from 'avatar'.

Thank you for your help and excuse me for my bad english!

Comment: usual caveats about method deprecation and injection. aside from that, you have another *table*, not another *database*, so what's the problem? Just JOIN one table to the other.

Comment: i've got the following code:   

SELECT a.id, a.naam, b.avatar
FROM tabela a
LEFT JOIN tabelb b ON a.id = b.id

I know it has to be something like this but don't know how to exact implent it in my code.

Tried different ways but it didn't work.

Comment: `mysql_query` is in the process of being retired. Are you sure you want to build an application using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be some ways but I'll show fast one.

```
<?php           
mysql_connect('', '', '');
mysql_select_db ("");

$sql = "SELECT u.id, name, avatar FROM jos_users AS u LEFT JOIN jos_comprofiler USING(id)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<div id='imgContainer'></div>";

echo "<select name='deelnemers' onchange='showAvatar(this.value);'>";
$avatars = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['avatar']){
        $avatars[$row['id']] = $row['avatar'];
}
echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
<script>
    var avatars = <?=json_encode($avatars)?>;
    //alert(avatars[5]);
    var avatarContainer = document.getElementById('imgContainer');
    function showAvatar(id) {
        if(avatars[id]===undefined) return false;
        avatarContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="/path/'+avatars[id]+'" />';
    }
</script>
```

This should work, with some modification for your code: img path, etc..

Comment: also if no avatar is found you can say to user: No avatar set, instead of `return false`. `if(avatars[id]==undefined) avatarContainer.innerHTML = 'No avatar for id: '+id;`

Comment: Thank you George for your response.

There are 2 points why i think it isn't working:

- Avatar is in the table jos_comprofiler. Now it is selected form the table jos_users?

- Also i had echo "<select name='deelnemers' onchange='copyId2textinput(this);'>"; in my code, the onchange value is what a need for my script.

Can i have 2 times 'onchange'?

Thank you very much!

Comment: No! avatar comes from jos_comprofiler, just I did not write in select statement jos_comprofiler.avatar because I think it's only table where 'avatar' field exists right? So MySQL can automatically understand where from to carry the data.

Comment: OK you can write `onchange="copyId2textinput(this)"`  and in `copyId2textinput` just call 'showAvatar' function. Something like this: `function copyId2textinput(obj) { showAvatar(obj.value); /* rest of code goes here*/ }`

Comment: Tried it like this but then my code doesn't work anymore:    '<script>
  function copyId2textinput(obj) {
   showAvatar(obj.value);
    document.getElementById('receive_user_id').value = select.value;
  }
</script>'

Comment: OK as long as you are not pro at scripting, it's expected that our work goes messy when implementing, so you can mail me your entire code and I can correct the code and make it work for your needs. my mail at gmail: george.garcha

Answer (score 1):

Query can be:

```
  SELECT `ju`.`id`, `ju`.`name`, `jcp`.`avatar`  FROM `jos_users` as `ju`
  LEFT JOIN `jos_comprofiler` as `jcp` ON (`ju`.`id` = `jcp`.`id`)
```

Here we use a left join, which means the jos_comprofiler does not need to exist for every jos_users. In those cases the field 'avatar' will be NULL.

Then you have in row the element 'avatar' which can be either NULL or a value.

```
if($row['avatar'] != NULL) echo "<img src=\"".$row['avatar']."\">";
```

or something :) good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my php knowledge is not so good. How can i implent this code into mine? Everytime i try i get a blank page.